# Best Java supported server/client protocol?

Tags: java, client-server, protocols

I'm in the process of writing a client/server application which should work message based. I would like re-use as much as possible instead of writing another implementation and curious what others are using.

Features the library should offer:

- **client and server side** functionality
- should work **message based**
- support **multi-threading**
- should **work behind load balancer / firewalls**

I did several tests with [HTTPCore](http://hc.apache.org), but the bottom line is that one has to implement both client and server, only the transport layer would be covered. RMI is not an option either due to the network related requirements.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

---

**Details**

My idea is to implement a client/server wrapper which handles the client communication (including user/password validation) and writes incoming requests to a JMS queue:

```
#1  User --> Wrapper (Check for user/password) --> JMS --> "Server"
#2  User polls Wrapper which polls JMS
```

Separate processes will handle the requests and can reply via wrapper to the clients. I'd like to use JMS because:

- it handles persistence quite well
- load balancing - it's easy to handle peaks by adding additional servers as consumer
- JMSTimeToLive comes in handy too

Unfortunately I don't see a way to use JMS on it's own, because clients should only have access to their messages and the setup of different users on JMS side doesn't sound feasible either.

Answer (score 3):

Well, HTTP is probably the best supported in terms of client and server code implementing it - but it may well be completely inappropriate based on your requirements. We'll need to actually *see* some requirements (or at least a vague idea of what the application is like) before we can really advise you properly.

Answer (score 2):

RMI works nicely for us. There are limitations, such as not being able to call back to the client unless you can connect directly to that computer (does not work if client is behind a firewall). You can also easily wrap your communication in SSL or tunnel it over HTTP which can be wrapped in SSL.

If you do end up using this remember to always set the serial version of a class that is distributed to the client. You can set it to 1L when you create it, or if the client already has the class use serialver.exe to discover the existing class's serial. Otherwise as soon as you change or add a public method or variable compatibility with existing clients will break.

static final long serialVersionUID = 1L

EDIT: Each RMI request that comes into the server gets its own thread. You don't have to handle this yourself.

EDIT: I think some details were added later in the question. You can tunnel RMI over HTTP, then you could use a load balancer with it.

I've recently started playing with Hessian and it shows a lot of promise. It natively uses HTTP which makes it simpler than RMI over HTTP and it's a binary protocol which means it's faster than all the XML-based protocols. It's very easy to get Hessian going. I recently did this by embedding Jetty in our app, configuring the Hessian Servlet and making it implement our API interface. The great thing about Hessian is it's simplicity... nothing like JMS or RMI over HTTP. There are also libraries for Hessian in other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the best-supported, if not best-implemented, client/server communications package for Java is Sun's RMI (Remote Method Invocation).  It's included with the standard Java class library, and gets the job done, even if it's not the fastest option out there.  And, of course, it's supported by Sun.  I implemented a turn-based gaming framework with it several years ago, and it was quite stable.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to make a suggestion based on the information given but possibly the use of TemporaryQueues e.g. dynamically created PTP destinations on a per client basis might fit the problem?

[Here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2007/04/10/designing-messaging-applications-with-temporary-queues.html) is a reasonable overview.

Comment: Hi Jim, which informations did I miss to add?

Tkx for the link to this great article, unfortunately the approach with TemporaryQueues doesn't work because it requires at least one static queue. It would be easy for a "bad guy" to access the message there and misuse the temporary queues.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried *[RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation)* or *[CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA)*? With both of them you can [distribute your logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) and create Sessions

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring....Then pick and choose the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

We're standardizing on Adobe's AMF as we're using Adobe Flex/AIR in the client-tier and Java6/Tomcat6/BlazeDS/Spring-Framework2.5/iBATIS2.3.4/ActiveMQ-JMS5.2 in our middle-tier stack (Oracle 10g back-end).

Because we're standardizing on Flex client-side development, AMF and BlazeDS (now better coupled to Spring thanks to Adobe and SpringSource cooperating on the integration), are the most efficient and convenient means we can employ to interact with the server-side.

We also heavily build on JMS messaging in the data center - BlazeDS enables us to bridge our Flex clients as JMS topic subscribers. That is extremely powerful and effective.

Our Flex .swf and Java .class code is bundled into the same .jar file for deployment. That way the correct version of the client code will be deployed to interact with the corresponding middle-tier java code that will process client service calls (or messaging operations). That has always been a bane of client-server computing - making sure the correct versions of the respective tiers are hooked up to each other. We've effectively solved that age-old problem with our particular approach to packaging and deployment.

All of our client-server interactions work over HTTP/HTTPS ports 80 and 443. Even the server-side messaging push we do with BlazeDS bridged to our ActiveMQ JMS message broker.