# Client side object creation of a server side class through transferring the class skeleton from server-to-client

Tags: java, web-services, object, client-server

Please pardon me if this question has been already asked before ...

I would like to create a client-server application preferrably using Java which requires the client program to invoke certain controller in the server program to encapsulate a single class originally resides in the server and deliver to the client side. The client will then decapsulate the class and create a new class object and perform certain task.

However, I am not sure how it would be possible to encapsulate a whole class in the server side and transfer back to the client side for object creattion, instantiation and perform required tasks.

For example, similar kind of application may be like client side JavaScript or Flash program execution for server side code. But I am not sure either JavaScript or Flash programs are operating like this way or not.

Please suggest me the possible ways of writing such kind of app in a very simplistic way to express this concept/idea or any possible links/examples to get a grip into.

Thanks a tlo...

Answer (score 1):

This is some kind of protocol question.

Similar Questions:

[Best Java supported server/client protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451004/best-java-supported-server-client-protocol)

[Client server protocol with XML messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182464/client-server-protocol-with-xml-messages)

You can try:

[RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html)

After setup RMI, it will help you en/decapsulate object transparently.

[Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)

Xstream will help you serialize/deserialize object into xml. You can use the xml for client/server communication.

[Protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

> Protocol Buffers are a way of encoding structured data in an efficient yet extensible format. Google uses Protocol Buffers for almost all of its internal RPC protocols and file formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your directions...its really helpful.